# Merging queries in Laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-jetstream

I am building a Jetstream Inertia SPA and trying to implement filters via the Vue watcher option. They work, but their query directives overwrite each other when another filter is activated.

I tried merging them using the `union()` method, as shown below, but it hasn't worked. So how might I go about merging all the conditional queries into one?

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Home', [
        'products' => Product::query()
            ->when(Request::input('lengthNormal'), function ($query, $lengthNormal) {
                if ($lengthNormal === "true") {
                    $test = Product::query()->where('length', '=', '1');
                    $query->union($test);
                }
            })
            ->when(Request::input('lengthRegular'), function ($query, $lengthRegular) {
                if ($lengthRegular === "true") {
                    $test2 = Product::query()->where('length', '=', '2');
                    $query->union($test2);
                }
            })
            ->paginate(10)
            ->withQueryString()
            ->through(fn($product) => [
                'id' => $product->id,
                'name' => $product->name,
                'length' => $product->length
            ]),
        'filters' => Request::only(['lengthNormal', 'lengthRegular'])
    ]);
});
```

Comment: could you share the original code?

Comment: The original just has $query->where('length', '=', '1/2'); as the if conditions.

It works with this, though both lengthNormal and lengthRegular are undefined on page load, only acquiring a value after the checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is useful for you.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Home', [
        'products' => Product::query()
            ->when(Request::input('lengthNormal'), function ($query, $lengthNormal) {
                if ($lengthNormal === "true") {
                    $query->orWhere('length', '=', '1');
                }
            })
            ->when(Request::input('lengthRegular'), function ($query, $lengthRegular) {
                if ($lengthRegular === "true") {
                    $query->orWhere('length', '=', '2');
                }
            })
            ->paginate(10)
            ->withQueryString()
            ->through(fn($product) => [
                'id' => $product->id,
                'name' => $product->name,
                'length' => $product->length
            ]),
        'filters' => Request::only(['lengthNormal', 'lengthRegular'])
    ]);
});
```